# Find all pairs of frequent itemsets that differ only in the last item

Tags: ruby, algorithm, apriori

I am trying to implement apriori algorithm, and having trouble writing method for generating candidate itemsets. Here is screenshot of this function.
[image]

Main problem are lines 2-5. I don't know how to get f1 and f2. f1 and f2 are arrays that differ in last item and last item from f1 is smaller than last item from f2.

Does anybody have an idea how to write this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = [1,2,3]
f2 = [1,2,4]
z = [f1,f2].transpose

if(((z[0...(z.size-1)].collect {|el| el[0] == el[1]}.uniq == [true])) & (z[z.size-1][0] < z[z.size-1][1])) do

# f1 = f2 , except the last element, where the last f1 element is smaller than the last f2 element

end
```